# formatting dates in Emacs when run as a daemon

Tags: init-file, emacsclient

I run Emacs on a Linux (actually Xubuntu 19.04) machine and my localization settings call for an Italian locale.

When generating timestamp, however, I'd like to have English months and weekday names. A quick look to the documentation gives the answer to this: set `system-time-locale` to "C" and that's all.

So I did and put

`(setq-default system-time-locale "C")`

in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and everything worked, *until I tried to run emacs as a daemon*.

If I start emacs in daemon mode (either starting it from the command line or using systemd) and then connect to the server with `emacsclient`, the above setting is not taken into account: if I ask the value of the variable I get "C", sure enough, but if I try

`(format-time-string  "%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M")`

I get the weekday in Italian (as per the `LC_TIME` environment variable) If I then set `system-time-locale` to the value it apparently already holds by:

`(setq-default system-time-locale "C")`

then `(format-time-string  "%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M")` prints the weekday in English as expected.

What is even more weird, at least for me, is that once I did the above call to `setq-default` it start using the right locale in all the client frames. either existing or created afterward.

It should be noted too that if I start the server from a running emacs instance (by `M-x server-start`) then everything works fine so my problem do really appears to be connected with frame creation.

I solved my problem, sort of, by adding something like this

`(lambda (&optional frame)
     (setq-default system-time-locale "C"))`

to `after-make-frame-functions` but I don't really like this solution; among other things because the above code doesn't need to be called at each frame creation: doing it once would be enough.

So, where is the question in all this? There are two, in fact:

1. why does the `system-time-locale` behave differently in server mode?
2. Is there a better or best-practice way to set this variable when emacs run as a daemon?

Comment: I suggest you report this to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Have you tried setting `system-time-locale` in your `site-start.el` file? This should be read at daemon start up.